# how to select the sheet and table based on the value of 2 cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to enter data using a pseudo-form. What I would like to get is to send the data in a specific table to a specific sheet that are declared by the value of the "Account" and "Bank" cell.

example, (the language I use in the file is Italian)

Pseudo-form for send data
Data - Account - Bank - Operazione - Dare - Avere

"Account" is a drop-down menu, with the choices "Utente_1, Utente_2, User_3, .. Utente_n (hypoteitically infinite "Utente" values).

"Bank" is a drop-down menu, with the choices "Banca_1, Banca_2, Banca_3 ... Banca_n (hypothetically infinite values of "Banca")

I tried with this little code and I can only send data to the "Worksheets (" Banca_1 "). Select"
I don't know very well with the VBA language, is there anyone who can help me?

```
Dim DATA As Date
Dim ACCOUNT As String
Dim BANK As String
Dim OPERAZIONE As String
Dim DARE As Currency
Dim AVERE As Currency

With Sheets("Home")
    DATA = .Cells(13, 1).Value
    ACCOUNT = .Cells(13, 2).Value
    BANK = .Cells(13, 3).Value
    OPERAZIONE = .Cells(13, 4).Value
    DARE = .Cells(13, 5).Value
    AVERE = .Cells(13, 6).Value 
End With

Call InsOper(DATA, ACCOUNT, BANK, OPERAZIONE, DARE, AVERE)

Dim riga As Integer
Dim v As Variant
riga = 12
Worksheets("Banca_1").Select 

Do
    riga = riga + 1
    v = Sheets("Banca_1").Cells(riga, 2).Value '
Loop While Not IsEmpty(v)

With Sheets("Banca_1") 
    .Cells(riga, 2).Value = DATA
    .Cells(riga, 3).Value = ACCOUNT
    .Cells(riga, 4).Value = BANK
    .Cells(riga, 5).Value = OPERAZIONI
    .Cells(riga, 6).Value = DARE
    .Cells(riga, 7).Value = AVERE
End With

MsgBox ("Ok! Operazione aggiunta con successo")
```

I have a sheet for each "bank" and on each sheet, there is a table for each "Utente"

I would like to get is to fill in the pesudo-from:

DATA: 12/12/2019

ACCOUNT: User_1

BANK: Banca_2

OPERAZIONI:PURCHASE

DARE: + 25.00 €

AVERE: -34.00 €

and send the data in the sheet called "Banca_2" in the tab called "Utente_1" in the first empty row available.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the changes you need to do are:

change `Dim BANK As String` to `Dim BANK As Variant`

and then all `("Banca_1")` to `(BANK)`

How it works? You declare name of the bank in the user form and then this will select the correct sheet.

Please be aware when using `INPUTBOX` you need to be precise with the bank name otherwise it will not find the sheet.

Let me know if it works

Comment: it didn't work, or maybe I didn't understand how to make corrections.
Unfortunately I am still at a basic level of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

When I declare name of Account (utente_1;utente_2,utente_3.....utente_N)and declare name of Bank (Banca_1;Banca_2;Banca_3....Banca_4) in the "operation form" and this select the correct sheet and correct formatted table on the correct sheet.
[example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o597gnqi5mbesip/Esempio%20per%20nome%20della%20variabile%20foglio.xlsm?dl=0)